# Combine two columns with Hour and Minutes into one with format %H:%M

Tags: datetime, python-3.6

I am a newbie to python and I am completely stuck trying to clean a data set. 
I have a dataframe with the columns HOUR and MINUTE representing the time (military style 24hrs) in which an accident occurred. 
[Columns HOUR and Minute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ2iW.png)

My intention is to combine both columns into one named 'TIME' in the format %H:%M. For example if HOUR is 2 and MINUTE is 40, I would like it to read 02:40, but I cannot find a way to make it work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You could go via the `datetime` class but it looks to me like simple formatting will do:

```
>>> hour = 2
>>> minute = 40
>>> f'{hour:02d}:{minute:02d}'
'02:40'
>>>
```